# Expanding the prime-ng's p-table row on click of the row

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

The link here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/rowexpansion shows an example of `p-table` where the rows can be expanded by clicking on the first column which uses the directive `pRowToggler`.

I am trying to achieve this toggling on the click of the row anywhere on the row.

I have tried looking for such an example but couldn't find one.
I have also tried to use the `[pRowToggler]` on the `ng-template` for the row but that didn't work either.

Can someone direct me how to achieve this behaviour ?

Comment: Not PrimeFaces related

Answer (score 8, accepted):

make table row selectable and wrap the row data into the link

```
<ng-template  pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns" class="ui-resizable-column">
        <a href="#" [pRowToggler]="rowData">
            {{rowData[col.field]}}           
            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

there is a sample project, it's not perfect there is some cosmetic work need to be done, but it shows the idea

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-width-7wnyzv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: That looks like something I needed. Hope it should work.

Answer (score 3):

My solution - simply call toggleRow on dlbclick event:

```
<p-table #table [value]="value">
   ...
   <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item let-expanded="expanded">
      <tr (dblclick)="table.toggleRow(item, $event)">
   ...
```

Comment: tried this way. But not working for me :(
I have used primeng table +reactiveForm+ row Expand.
When i click single row, all row getting expand..
Any suggestions will be helpful forme

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pRowToggler directive from the first column and add it to the row .This will let you expand the row wherever you click on the row

```
    <tr [pEditableRow]="data" [pRowToggler]="config">
    <td style="width: 100%;" pTooltip="Expand Row" tooltipPosition="top">
    <a style="padding: 7px;border-radius: 3px;color: black;height: 70px;cursor: pointer;" href="#"`enter code here`>
    <i [ngClass]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-right'"></i>
    </a>
    </td>
    ...
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this just using this approach, it might help someone else

For my case I wanted to fetch data from api then upon fetching data toggleRow

```
  <p-table #dt [value]="value">
       ...
       <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item let-expanded="expanded">
          <tr (click)="toggleRow(item, $event, dt)">
    
        ...
    </td>
```

in your ts file

```
   toggleRow = (item: any, event: Event, dt: any) => {
    this.apiUrl.getRecords({ queryId: item.id }).subscribe((response: Item) => {
      if (response.code == 200) {

        dt.toggleRow(event);

        item.records = response?.data;
      } else {
        console.log('No records found');
      }
    }, (error: Error) => {
      console.log('Error');
    });
  };
```